# Image renders differently on iPhone 8 and 8 plus

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-resizing, resizable

I try to add programatically an image used as a progress bar above a progress bar image background.

But it renders differently on iPhone 8 vs iPhone 8+:
[image]

The code used is the following:

```
private func updateGauge() {
    // Progress value to apply to not overedge content view
    let applicableProgress = 1.0

    // Get proper image
    self.image = getImageColorFrom(progress: applicableProgress)

    // Progress bar frame
    if let superviewHeight = self.superview?.frame.size.height {

        // Height
        let progressViewHeight = CGFloat(applicableProgress) * (superviewHeight-borderVertical*2)

        // Width
        let progressViewWidth = self.superview!.frame.size.width - (borderHorizontal*2)

        // Build y position
        let yPos = superviewHeight - progressViewHeight

        // Finally set frame
        self.frame = CGRect(x: borderHorizontal-decalageHorizontal, y: yPos-borderVertical+decalageVertical, width: progressViewWidth, height: progressViewHeight)
    }
}

private func getImageColorFrom(progress: Double) -> UIImage {
    let image: UIImage

    // Retrieve the good background color based on progress value
    if progress == 0 {
        image = UIImage()
    }
    else if progress < greenMaxValue {
        image = UIImage(progressBar: ProgressBarColor.Green)// "jaugeverte.png"
    }
    else if progress < orangeMaxValue {
        image = UIImage(progressBar: ProgressBarColor.Orange)// "jaugeorange.png"
    }
    else {
        image = UIImage(progressBar: ProgressBarColor.Red)// "jaugerouge.png"
    }

    // Build resizable image
    return image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch)
}
```

For information, both images are used as IBOutlet, that's why we don't have addSubview() calls in the code.
I logged frames sizes and here is the result:

```
progressViewBackgroundFrame (8 / 8+): (17.0, 67.0, 45.0, 460.0) / (17.0, 71.0, 45.0, 525.0)
progressViewFrame (8 / 8+): (8.0, 9.0, 27.0, 443.0) / (8.0, 9.0, 27.0, 508.0)
```

Why the image renders differently on iPhone 8 and 8+? Image frames are what is expected, is it a problem with resizableImage function?

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: You have resizing mode as stretch.. What about aspect scaling?

Comment: How to do this ? The only available options for resizingMode are .stretch and .tile (already tried this last one but it's not what is expected).

Comment: Thanks for your help but it was finally a problem with the pictures itselves (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 8 is a `@2x` image scale factor device and iPhone 8+ is a `@3x` image scale factor device. While this doesn't affect points, which is what we use in Swift, it does affect the image rendering. Images for plus-size iPhones must be 1.5x bigger in pixel size than non-plus iPhones. Also verify in your assets catalog you have two separate images for `@2x` and `@3x`.

Comment: I have both '@2x' and '@3x' for all gauges color. But it seems, they are not correctly sized as '@3x' is not 1.5x bigger than '@2x'. I'll test after resizing the images.
Besides, is there any problem having only gauge@2x.png and gauge@3x.png (I mean not having gauge.png) ?

Comment: An `@3x` device physically displays 3x3 pixels for each point and an `@2x` device physically displays 2x2 pixels for each point. That's why an `@3x` device looks sharper than a `@2x` and why an `@2x` looks sharper than `@1x` (pre-Retina). Therefore, the `@3x` image must be **exactly** 1.5x bigger in pixel size because the iPhone+ has more pixels to cover (1.5x more).

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Last question then: is there any problem having only gauge@2x.png and gauge@3x.png (meaning not having gauge.png) ?

Comment: If you don't want to support non-Retina devices, which virtually nobody does anyway, then you only need `@2x` and `@3x`. Some people just make `@3x` images and use them for their `@2x` formats but then you aren't getting pixel-perfect rendering. So when you make your images (i.e. in Adobe), make sure that when you create the image size for `@2x` that it will scale without decimals to `@3x`. For example, a 5x5 image `@2x` must have a 7.5x7.5 `@3x` version, which is not desirable. If you made is 6x6 instead, it's `@3x` would be 9x9, which is now desirable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as soon as I resized the @3x correctly, it worked :) just one more question from your last comment: does it mean if I don't have gauge.png (meaning only '@2x and @3x), nothing will be displayed on not-Retina screen?

Comment: If a project is missing 1x assets, iOS will automatically downscale the 2x version which isn't ideal but at least forces something to be displayed on screen.